# Como usar AirPrint para imprimir um texto a partir de um UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, impressora

Alguém poderia indicar um tutorial, ou sample code explicando como imprimir um texto a partir de um UITextField.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Cheque se o device pode imprimir

Basta checar `isPrintingAvailable` no `UIPrintInteractionController`:

```
if ([UIPrintInteractionController isPrintingAvailable]){
    // Chamar impressão
} else {
    // Fazer algo que você julgar interessante
}
```

## Usando o [`UIPrintInteractionController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInteractionController_Class/index.htmlhttps://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInfo_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/UIPrintInfo)

Acesse o singleton usando `[UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController]`

```
sharedPrintController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
```

Sete a *property* `printingItem` para o item que vai imprimir, pode ser das classes  `NSURL`, `NSData`, `UIImage`, ou  `ALAsset`

Usando texto simples você pode simplesmente fazer

```
sharedPrintController.printingItem = [self.myUITextField.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Crie um completion handler caso julgue necessário:

```
void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
     ^(UIPrintInteractionController *printController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
     if (!completed && error) {
         NSLog(@"Erro: %@", error);
     }
}
```

Mostre:

```
[sharedPrintController presentFromBarButtonItem:self.rightButton animated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

---

## Opcionais

### Usando [`UIPrintInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPrintInfo_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/UIPrintInfo)

Você pode setar informações sobre a impressão usado a *property* `printInfo` do seu *controller*

```
UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
 printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
 printInfo.jobName = "Nome do Job";
 sharedPrintController.printInfo = printInfo;
```

### Se preferir você pode usar um [`UISimpleTextPrintFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISimpleTextPrintFormatter_Class/index.html)

```
 UISimpleTextPrintFormatter *textFormatter = [[UISimpleTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithAttributedText:self.myUITextField.attributedText];
 textFormatter.startPage = 0;
 textFormatter.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0); // margens de uma polegada
 textFormatter.maximumContentWidth = 6 * 72.0;
 sharedPrintController.printFormatter = textFormatter;
 sharedPrintController.showsPageRange = YES;
```

Inspirado em: [iPhone SDK - simple print file](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/67176-airprint-tutorial-simple-print-file-30-lines-code.html)

Comment: no inicio, tem uma checagem se é possível imprimir. Neste caso, o que pode impossibilitar a impressão? Ou seja, o que pode fazer o `if ([UIPrintInteractionController isPrintingAvailable])` retornar `NO`?

Comment: DICA: Kit de teste de hardware para o Xcode:

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=hardware%20io%20tools#